# How to Load/Save data to CosmosDB through an HTTP trigger?

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an app that will save and load json file data through a cosmosDB. I figured out how to save/load with a storage account, 
but this app calls for ID's for every user so they have their own JSON file with their progress.

Anyone have insight on loading **JSON** with a **Azure Function call**? The program is with Unity so there are already gits for calling azure functions easily.

I just need to know how to take a user's name and password and save their file to the DB. I am familiar with SQL so my problem is the connection between apps. **(Unity and AzureDB)**

**Edit**: All I need is guidance in adding json files to a collection with a specific ID for each user.

Thanks!

Comment: see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-functions-http-trigger And this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/videos/create-an-azure-cosmos-db-trigger-in-an-azure-function-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Not sure what, specifically, you're asking. Cosmos DB is just a database. Can you please edit to clarify your specific challenge? (also fyi - please don't store a password anywhere).

Comment: The two links above are helping me. I might be explaining it very complex and its probably a simple concept.

Comment: Usually, user authentication returns a session token. That token is passed with the header for each request so the server knows if the request is allowed or not. Then the server knows who is asking so it can return the data appropriately. If you skipped authentication then, the filename would most likely contain the id of the user, myUserId.json.